# Drag and Select images and then change order by dragging using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-dnd

I am developing a front end application using react hooks where I need to upload one/multiple images.
Then i need to implement two features on the uploaded images (shown as bootstrap grid)

**1.Drag/click to select one/multiple images (I am using react-selecto library for this)**

**2.Drag and change the order of the selected images (I and using react-dnd for this)**

The problem here is:

**1.When I use react-dnd alone it works absolutely fine.**

**2.When I use both react-selecto and react-dnd, then react-dnd no more works. Only react-selecto works.**

To get a more clearer picture, when both the libraries are used together, user can select one/more images by clicking/dragging but after that when user tries to change the order by dragging selected images,nothing happens (no mouse response) and images cannot be moved from its position.

Thanks in advance. Need help.

The code is here:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import {HTML5Backend} from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import UploadForm from "./upload";
import Images from "./images";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const addImages = (images, description) => {
    let t = {
      images: images,
      description: description,
    };
    setData((data) => data.concat(t));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useState", data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <UploadForm onSubmit={addImages} />
      <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
        <Images imgData={data}/>
      </DndProvider>  
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**images.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Image from "./image";
import update from "immutability-helper";
import Selecto from "react-selecto";

const Images = ({ imgData }) => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let temp = [];
    imgData.forEach((item) => {
      item.images.forEach((image) => {
        let t = {
          key: image.text,
          photo: image,
          description: item.description,
        };
        temp.push(t);
      });
    });
    setImages(temp);
  }, [imgData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(images);
  }, [images]);

  const moveImage = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    const draggedImage = images[dragIndex];
    setImages(
      update(images, {
        $splice: [
          [dragIndex, 1],
          [hoverIndex, 0, draggedImage],
        ],
      })
    );
  };

  const imgList = images.map((img, index) => (
    <Image image={img} moveImage={moveImage} index={index}/>
  ));


  return (
    <div className="container p-5 elements selecto-area">
      <Selecto
        dragContainer={".elements"}
        selectableTargets={[".imageCube"]}
        hitRate={100}
        selectByClick={true}
        selectFromInside={false}
        toggleContinueSelect={["shift"]}
        onSelect={(e) => {
          e.added.forEach((el) => {
            el.classList.add("selected");
            console.log(el);
          });
          e.removed.forEach((el) => {
            el.classList.remove("selected");
          });
        }}
      ></Selecto>
      <div className="row">{imgList}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

**image.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useDrag, useDrop } from "react-dnd";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const type = "Image";

const Image = ( { image, moveImage, index } ) => {

  const ref = useRef(null);

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type, id: image.id, index },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    })
  });

  const [, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: type,
    hover(item) {
      if (!ref.current) {
        return;
      }
      const dragIndex = item.index;
      const hoverIndex = index;

      if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) { 
        return;
      }
      moveImage(dragIndex, hoverIndex);
      item.index = hoverIndex;
    }
  });

  drag(drop(ref));
  console.log(ref);

  return(
    <div className="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div className="hvrbox imageCube" ref={ref} style={{ opacity: isDragging ? 0.7 : 1 }}>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <img src={image.photo.preview} alt="" width="210" height="150"/>
            <div className="mt-1 text-center">
              <strong>{image.photo.text}</strong>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="hvrbox-layer_top hvrbox-layer_scale">
          <div className="hvrbox-text">
            {image.description ? image.description : image.photo.text}
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}; 

export default Image;
```

Thanks in advance. Need help.